# Изменить картинку по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть несколько кнопок, нужно чтобы по нажатию на каждую подставлялась своя картинка в блок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $(".images a").click(function(){
        var source = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#image").html('<img src="'+source+'" width="200" alt="">');
        return false;
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image"></div>

<div class="images">
    <a href="http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-09/animals_hero_panda.jpg">1</a>
    <a href="https://d1o50x50snmhul.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/17153147/gettyimages-590483570.jpg">2</a>
    <a href="http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-10/animals_hero_fennec2.jpg">3</a>
</div>
```